# Item Template not showing up in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I am creating Item Template using the Create Item Template Wizard in Visual Studio. But it is not showing up in Add New Items. All default settings but lost where to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:
[Add Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjiKj.png)

And the code for the template item you want for this:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>class1.cs</DefaultName>
    <Name>Myproject class1</Name>
    <Description>Myproject Class</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>Myprojectclass1.png</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System.Linq</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System.Threading.Tasks</Assembly>
      </Reference>
    </References>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">class1.cs</ProjectItem>
    <CustomParameters>  
        <CustomParameter Name="$username$" Value="$safeitemrootname$"/> 
        <CustomParameter Name="$rootnamespace$" Value="$safeitemrootname$"/>
        <CustomParameter Name="$registeredorganization$" Value="$safeitemrootname$"/>
    </CustomParameters>  
  </TemplateContent>
    <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>MyProjectWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=f7a1fcb8d457e160</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>MyProjectWizard.WizardImplementation</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

I use the key to access the template item and call a form for the item.